# Mvc UserControl using HtmlHelper with HelperResult and MvcHtmlString

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm developing an application in asp mvc, and I want to create some friendly controls for developers, like Server controls in asp.net WebForms . In this case, I want to create a bootstrap panel that has some fixed html and render inside a template of items. I am doing it this way:

```
public static MvcHtmlString BootPanel<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, HelperResult> template, string title = "")
    {

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.Append("<div class='panel panel-info'>");
     sb.Append("<div class='panel-heading'>");
     sb.Append(title);
     sb.Append("</div>");
     sb.Append("<div class='panel-body'>");
        
     var hr = new HelperResult(writer =>
              {
                 foreach (var item in items)
                {
                  template(item).WriteTo(writer);
                }
       });

      sb.Append(hr.ToHtmlString());
      sb.Append("</div>");
      sb.Append("</div>");
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

This is the razor View:

```
@{
  var videoGames = new[] {
      new VideoGame {nombre = "Shadows of mordor", precio = 66},
      new VideoGame {nombre = "Spiderman", precio = 50}
      };
   }    

  @videoGames.BootPanel(@<div>
                            @item.nombre  &nbsp;  @item.precio
                        </div>
                      , "Titulo")
```

---

The output is rendered correctly using the bootstrap classes:

[image]

The question is. Is this a correct way of implementing this kind of control?

**EDIT:**

Following your answers I updated the helper yo use TagBuilder:

```
public static MvcHtmlString BootPanel<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, HelperResult> template, string title = "")
    {
        TagBuilder PanelDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
        PanelDiv.AddCssClass("panel panel-info");

        TagBuilder PanelHeading = new TagBuilder("div");
        PanelHeading.AddCssClass("panel-heading");
        PanelHeading.SetInnerText(title);

        TagBuilder PanelBody = new TagBuilder("div");
        PanelBody.AddCssClass("panel-body");
       
        var hr = new HelperResult(writer =>
        {


            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                template(item).WriteTo(writer);
            }

        });

        PanelBody.InnerHtml = hr.ToHtmlString();

        PanelDiv.InnerHtml = PanelHeading.ToString() +
                             PanelBody.ToString();

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(PanelDiv.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: according to me there is no wrong in your approach

Comment: It's fine. The only thing I would suggest would be using `TagBuilder` instead of `StringBuilder`. It's far easier to ensure you output clean sanitized HTML that way, and it's easier to work with for things like adding attributes, CSS classes, etc.

Comment: How can you nest controls with tagbuilder?

Comment: `outerDivBuilder.InnerHTML = innerDivBuilder.ToString();`. You can also use `+=` to append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you encode the output string before returning since if some one writes a javascript for title then it results in script injection. Apart from that it looks, but instead using hard coded  tags you may use TagBuilder class to build your html code. See this  [example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs).